# Promise returns an object instead of the actual string value [Javascript w/ Firebase]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

So I researched about Promises and concluded that by using the `.then`, it will "actually execute" the asynchronous function inside it. Then, I proceed on updating my code to this:

```js
function getCurrentKey(){
  return tailorRef.once('value').then(function(data){
   data.forEach(function(childData){
    if ( (loggedUname == childData.val().tUsername) && (loggedPword == childData.val().tPassword) ){
     Ukey = childData.key;
    }
   });
        return Ukey;
  });
 }
 
 currentKey = getCurrentKey();
 
 console.log("key = " + currentKey);
```

*NOTE: the var currentKey is global*

The expected output in the console would be `key = "some unique key"` but instead, it shows `key = [object Promise]`. I tried to put `.val()` after the `childData.key` to actually get the value and not the object, but it didn't work.

Is there something wrong with my Promise implementation or its structure? or is my conclusion wrong?

Comment: you have two return statements inside `getCurrentKey` - the second one is ignored - therefore, what that function returns is the Promise returned by `return tailorRef.once('value').then(function(data){`

Comment: @guest271314 - not really. It's quite difficult to explain asynchronous code to someone that doesn't understand asynchronous code

Comment: @JaromandaX ah, my bad. Sorry I didn't realized it sooner.

Comment: there's more to the problem then that, because you'll need to know how to use Promises

Answer (score 0):

Because the first return happens before the `resolve` part is executed.

If you really want to print your currentKey, do something like this.

```
function getCurrentKey(){
 tailorRef.once('value').then(function(data){
        data.forEach(function(childData){
            if ( (loggedUname == childData.val().tUsername) && (loggedPword == childData.val().tPassword) ){
                currentKey = childData.key;
                printCurrentKey(currentKey);
            }
        });
    }); 
}


printCurrentKey(key){
  console.log(key)
}
```

Note: Do take care of the scope while calling `printCurrentKey`.

Comment: My main goal was not really to print it, but to store it to the global variable `currentKey` so that I can use the key of the logged in user in other functions. I was just printing it to test that I was getting the right value.

Comment: So what I really want to do is make the function `getCurrentKey()` return the corresponding unique key that matches the given username and password in the login box. I visioned that `currentKey = getCurrentKey()` will store the processed unique key to the said variable

Comment: it won't work. You can only return the key to a function which sets the global variable. Your assignment `currentKey = getCurrentKey()` means happens much before the api call finishes. And the program doesn't wait there, it moves on. So when the api call actually finishes, it invokes the callback function(the pointer to the function) that is registered. So in your case, whatever you want to do with currentkey can be done inside the printCurrentKey in the example above.

Comment: is there a way around it? or are you telling me that storing the key to a global variable is completely impossible?